# Keyword not supported in MySQL's connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

To get the connection string from my App.config I write this code:

```
ConnectionStringSettings settings
    = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["livresEntities"];

string connectString = settings.ConnectionString;

Console.WriteLine("Original: "+ connectString);
```

The result (I use Data Model .edmx file):

> Original: metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=livres"

But when I want to change the password or the uid using this line:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder
    = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);<br>
```

It give me the following error:

> Keyword not supported

Why? If there is any tutorial on how to secure MySQL's connection string using a Model (.edmx) it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid connection string to me.  It appears to be some sort of Entity Framework configuration that has a connection string inside.

Comment: I think that too but I don't know the difference between connection string of EF and MySql, anyway how can I modify the password using this EF's connectionString

Comment: Yea I don't know EF that well.  I'm wondering if there's an API that can parse that configuration and extract the connection string.  Hopefully someone with some EF expertise will chime in.